# How to get the returned value to print any information to Log in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I tried this but could not use the returned value that is TRUE from 
- (BOOL) returnTrueOrFalse. The compiler generates error as use of undeclared identifier.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface SampleClass : NSObject
- (BOOL) returnTrueOrFalse;
- (void) implementResult;
@end

@implementation SampleClass

- (BOOL) returnTrueOrFalse{
    return TRUE;
}

- (void) implementResult{
    if ((BOOL)returnTrueOrFalse){
        NSLog(@"I am called because the above function returned true value");
    }
}
@end

int main( int argc, const char *argv[]){
    SampleClass *sampleClass = [[SampleClass alloc] init];
    [sampleClass implementResult];

}
```

Comment: Does that NSLog fire? It should. Where are you not able to access the value? You're not actually referencing it anywhere other than inside the `implementationResult` void, and even then, you're only evaluating it not actually assigning it.

Comment: NSLog never gets fired. The compiler gives error message.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function/method as a variable

```
   - (void) implementResult{
        if ([self returnTrueOrFalse]){
            NSLog(@"I am called because the above function returned true value");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wy do we need to add self in the function call?

Comment: how to access the returned value from returnTrueOrFalse after changing it ti +(BOOL)returnTrueOrFalse. Using self i cannot get the result.

Comment: I missed that. Exactly. You've created a method, not a property with a getter/setter method. You call methods internal to the class by using `self`.

Comment: Thanx. I knew something about self now

Comment: @remus how to access it if we use + instead of - in (BOOL)returnTrueOrFalse

Comment: Same way, but that would be a class method - you wouldn't instantiate an instance of your class.

Comment: I figured it out. But can you please tell me, why we need to use the class name while calling the function.

Comment: to call static method(+) use `[SampleClass returnTrueOrFalse];`

Comment: @JivanBhandari suggest you pick up a beginners guide to iOS and Objective-C - these are fundamental principles that you'll need to understand if you want to progress.

Comment: can you please post me the link for beginners guide.